# Why I get import declarations issues with yeoman and knockout generator?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bower, yeoman, yeoman-generator

SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module with Yeoman.

I installed Yeoman and generator-ko for knockoutjs. I must say I never used Yeoman before but I heard it's a magic wand for frontend developments.

Steps I did:

```
sudo npm i -g yo bower http-server
sudo npm i -g generator-ko 
mkdir testing && cd testing && npm init
yo ko
http-server src
```

In the browser's console I get:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

From a file called **startup.js** which looks like:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import ko from 'knockout';
import 'knockout-projections'
import * as router from './router';
```

The package generator-ko looks a bit outdated (2 years old) would that be the issue here? If so, which package should I use then to start using knockoutjs?

EDIT: I tried with classical-ko which is more recent (~6 months) and I get the same error :/ ARG)

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel stupid, in the demo I watched the guy was calling **http-server** but I had to actually call **gulp serve:dist** or **gulp serve:src**.

Sorry for wasted time.